# Sqlite thread modes and sqlite misuse paradox

Tags: multithreading, sqlite, misuse

I have a project where i should use multiple tables to avoid keeping dublicated data in my sqlite file(Even though i knew usage of several tables was nightmare).

In my application i am reading data from one table in some method and inserting data into another table in some other method. When i do this i am getting from sqlite step function, error code 21 which is sqlite misuse.

Accoding to my researches that was because i was not able to reach tables from multi threads.

Up to now, i read the sqlite website and learned that there are 3 modes to configurate sqlite database:

1) singlethread: you have no chances to call several threads.
2) multithread: yeah multi thread; but there are some obstacles.
3) serialized: this is the best match with multithread database applications.

if `sqlite3_threadsafe() == 2`  returns true then yes your sqlite database is serialized and this returned true, so i proved it for myself.

then i have a code to configurate my sqlite database for serialized to take it under guarantee.

```
sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED);
```

when i use above codes in class where i read and insert data from 1 table works perfectly :). But if i try to use it in class where i read and insert data from 2 tables (actually where i really need it) problem sqlite misuse comes up.

I checked my code where i open and close database, there is no problem with them. they work unless i delete the other.

I am using ios5  and this is really a big problem for my project. i heard that instagram uses postgresql may be this was the reason ha? Would you suggest postgresql or sqlite at first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me like you've got two things mixed up.

### Single vs. multi-threaded

Single threaded builds are only ever safe to use from *one* thread of your code because they lack the mechanisms (mutexes, critical sections, etc.) internally that permit safe use from several. If you are using multiple threads, use a multi-threaded build (or expect “interesting” trouble; *you have been warned*).

SQLite's thread support is pretty simple. With a multi-threaded build, particular connections should only be used from a single thread (except that they can be initially opened in another).

All recent (last few years?) SQLite builds are happy with access to a single database from multiple *processes*, but the degree of parallelism depends on the…

### Transaction type

SQL in general supports multiple types of transaction. SQLite supports only a subset of them, and its default is SERIALIZABLE. This is the safest mode of access; it simulates what you would see if only one thing could happen at a time. (Internally, it's implemented using a scheme that lets many readers in at once, but only one writer; there's some cleverness to prevent anyone from starving anyone else.)

SQLite also supports read-uncommitted transactions. This increases the amount of parallelism available to code, but at the risk of readers seeing information that's not yet been guaranteed to persist. Whether this matters to you depends on your application.